# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, centos7

I have installed Centos7 update, removed MariaDB and done a fresh install of MySQL - additionally I have removed it and reinstalled it but everytime I connect to mysql -u root -p I get the titled error. Additionally I *have* looked at other tickets associated with this but still not making progress. If I run service mysqld restart it says "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  mysqld.service" and then just hangs. Really not a linux expert so not sure what is causing this?

Comment: That sounds like your MySQL daemon is unable to start. Check the logs - `/var/log/mysqld.log`. What errors is it giving you? If you installed an older version of MySQL over MariaDB, it may not be able to convert the data files, if you left your `/var/lib/mysql` directory intact.

Comment: I'm getting the following error(s) about Innodb:

2014-10-02 17:41:17 7948 [ERROR] InnoDB: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size 640 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
2014-10-02 17:41:17 7948 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt.

Comment: I removed the 3x ibdata files and logs and restarted it and I get an error. I'm happy to fully remove it (as theres no data there) but have already tried that. Leaving now but back tomorrow.

Comment: If you do not need the data from the old database, you should delete everything within `/var/lib/mysql`. It will recreate the system databases, and should then be able to start.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem and found out a few things after digging around.  MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for mysql.  On the new system, mysql is the MariaDB client (although I'm not clear on what that means).  I checked to see if the service was running:

```
service mysqld status
```

which indicated:

> `Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysqld.service
>   mysqld.service
>   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>   Active: inactive (dead)`

In other words, the mysqld service is not running.

Starting the service worked for me:

```
`systemctl start mariadb.service`
```

Now all the mysql commands work as expected.

To tie the last knot, enable the service at boot:

```
`systemctl enable mariadb.service`
```

Comment: So after installation, I get the same error, and this post solves my problem. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'socket=' entry in your /etc/my.cnf within the *[mysqld]* section:

```
[mysqld1]
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock1
```

An alternate method is to provide the '-hhost' & '-Pport' parameters to the 'mysqladmin' or 'mysql' commands, to avoid using the socket.

```
mysql -u user -hservername -P3006 -p   -Dschema
mysqladmin -u user -p -hhostname -Pport
```

Comment: To verify the mysqld is actually running, use the command 'pgrep -fl mysqld'.  In the output you should see 2 very long entries (each wrapped several times across the terminal). One line beginning with 'mysqld_safe' and another line beginning with 'mysqld'.   The 'end' of the wrapped line for 'mysqld' should also contain '--port=xxxx'  Try using that value for the 'mysql  . . . -Pxxxx' command line.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've run that and all I see is 9818 mysqld_safe and 9970 mysqld. I'm going to try removing and re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dir fixed it - deleted the dir (with rm -rf "dir name") and then unintalled mysql "yum remove mysql mysql-server" then reinstalled "yum install mysql-server" and ran "service mysqld start"

If you have this problem with the start mysql service hanging - check the logs /var/log/mysqld.log as suggested by Jeremiah.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the MariaDB log file, you may see that the issue is related to creating pid file. To solve it: create the PID directory then change its owner to mysql:mysql